# Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions between String and Object {String}

Tags: vb.net, winforms, toolstrip, toolstripitem

I am trying to clean my ways as a beginner programmer by using `Option Strict On`. I managed to clean all errors except this one.
I am using the Tag property of a ToolStrip for some text information.  Clicking on the ToolStrip, I need to remember the value of the Tag in a string and change the value of that Tag.

How can I convert the *Object {String}* sender.tag to a *String* and the *String* myString and an *Object {String}*?

```
Private Sub ToolStrip_ItemClicked(sender As Object, e As ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs) Handles ToolStrip.ItemClicked
    Dim myString As String = sender.tag
    sender.tag = "It is selected"
    'more code...
End Sub
```

Edit: see here a screenshot of the relevant part of the code:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have `Option Strict On` right now? You cannot write this with that option `On`: `Dim myString As String = sender.tag`: sender is an `Object` Type, `Object` doesn't have a `Tag` property (`e.ClickedItem` can have it), so the error is different.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you for the reply. I update the question with a screenshot of the errors.

Comment: As mentioned, `sender` (as you can see in the handler definition) is an Object, `Object` doesn't have a Tag property. So of course you cannot ask to read the value of a property that the Type doesn't provide. You need to cast `sender` to the actual Type. But, the Tag of what UI element you really want to read? Have you set a Breakpoint there and inspected what `sender` actually is? Not the clicked Item. Do you want to read the Tag property of which UI element?

Comment: @Jimi, I am using a Winform with several buttons in the toolbar. Each button has the property Tab [ToolBarButton.Tag Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolbarbutton.tag). After I created the toolbar, I double-clicked on it and the Private Sub in the screenshot was created in the VB code. I added the lines I showed you. The code runs fine if Strict is Off. I tried _.ToString_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good that you have titled your question generically. And you need a generic answer.

`Option Strict On` is a good thing. It makes harder to code but performance at runtime will increase because there will be less implicit data type conversions.

Lets take your code `...sender As Object...` and `...sender.tag..`
This is a typical thing in .net. Often you see a parameter of type `object`, which means, any data type can be passed. Object does not have all the properties and methods defined that belong to that data type.

For example

```
Dim oTxt as object = new TextBox()
```

`oTxt` will not automatically have property `Text`. You need to `cast`. When you know 100% the object type, do

```
dim str as string = DirectCast(oTxt, TextBox).Text
```

But sometimes you don't know what `Type` is in your `object`. In this case you try casting and then check for `null`

```
dim txtBx as TextBox = TryCast(oTxt, TextBox)
if txtBx IsNot Nothing Then str = txtBx.Text
```

Your real problem is that you need to understand type casting. You should cast it explicitly even if you don't have `Options Strinct On` because when you do `x = sender.tag` implicitly, you really using a **late binding**, which is bad for performance. And this also opens doors for potential runtime errors.

Your topics of research should be: type casting, late binding, boxing/unboxing

Comment: @t-s, thank you for the lesson. I added it to the list of stuff I have to learn. :-)   I tried to use Dim myString As String = TryCast(sender.tag, String), but I get the same error: BC30574 Option Strict On disallows late binding.

Comment: @Florin **sure!** both `sender` and `tag` are objects. Hence you need to add another cast `Dim myString As String = TryCast(DirectCast(sender, Control).tag, String)` But if you have `string` in your object, object has ToString definition. Hence this is enough `Dim myString As String = DirectCast(sender, Control).Tag.ToString()`

Comment: @T-S, Thank you. I think I understood what you did: instead of using DirectCast on sender.tag to convert it to a string, you are converting 'sender' to a Control, then you are reading the control's tag. Unfortunately it doesn't work. While it doesn't give me an error at compilation, it gives me a runtime error: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'."

Comment: @T-S, piggybacking on your answer, this works: = DirectCast(sender, ToolStripMenuItem).Tag.ToString Thank you for all the help.

Comment: @Florin Ok. The error is self-explanatory. Apparently `ToolStripMenuItem` is not deriving from `Control`. So, just replace `Control` with `ToolStripMenuItem`

Answer (score 6):

If you want to read the Tag Property of a [ToolstripItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem), you need to read the Tag of the Item selected. This is provided by the [e.ClickedItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripitemclickedeventargs.clickeditem) property of the [ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripitemclickedeventargs) object:

> Gets the item that was clicked on the ToolStrip.

If you want to read the Tag property of the ToolStrip this Item belongs to, cast `sender` to ToolStrip (or Control, the base class this property belongs to) and cast its Tag property to String.

Note: when you double-click a ToolStrip Control, an `ItemClicked` handler is created because this is the [default event of that Control](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ToolStrip.cs,42). The event is related to the ToolStrip object, so the `sender` object in the event handler will be the reference of the ToolStrip instance that raised the event.

The [Tag Property](http://Control.Tag) is of Type `Object`, that's why you need to cast that, too.

```
Private Sub ToolStrip_ItemClicked(sender As Object, e As ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs) Handles ToolStrip.ItemClicked
    Dim itemTagAsString As String = e.ClickedItem.Tag?.ToString()

    Dim toolStripTagAsString = DirectCast(sender, ToolStrip).Tag?.ToString()
    ' Or, cast to Control, the Tag Property belongs to the base class
    Dim toolStripTagAsString = DirectCast(sender, Control).Tag?.ToString()
End Sub
```

Check the Type of `itemTtag` in these examples (with `Option Infer On`):

```
Dim itemTtag = e.ClickedItem.Tag
Dim itemTtag = e.ClickedItem.Tag?.ToString()
```

So it's more clear why this is not a valid statement:

```
Dim itemTtag As String = e.ClickedItem.Tag
```

Note: the [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) (`?`, aka Elvis), is used here because the Tag could be null (`Nothing`). If it is, you won't get an exception, just an empty string.

Comment: I feel like up-voting just once is insufficient.

Comment: @jmcilhinney  Thanks. Not sure why you say so, but I appreciate the comment :)

Comment: @Jimi, thank you for the detailed example. I understand how to use the "e" object, but I need to use the "sender" object because this is the only one that has any information in other cases like the ToolStripSplitButton.

Comment: As mentioned, the `sender` object represents the ToolStrip itself. Not the Controls you add to it. If you click a child Control, this is referenced by the `e.ClickedItem` property. The MenuItems of a SplitMenu don't belong to the ToolStrip, so when you select one of these, the event is not raised. As already asked in comments, the Tags of which Controls do you need? The ToolStrip itself (already in the answer)? Its child Controls (already in the answer)? The MenuItems of a SplitButton? <- The latter cannot be included because these, as described, don't raise the event.

Comment: Yes. This is the other case where I have errors.

Comment: Try to explain more explicitly which are the Controls you want the get the Tag property from.

Comment: @Jimi, thank you for cleaning the text of my initial post.